# High frequency relay options for 5V 20A DC

Tags: relay, dc, frequency, switching

While researching for a while upon relays, I had a hard time finding out how to choose a relay that can switch high DC currents at frequencies up to 20MHZ. I found those solid state relays, but most of them seem to work only for AC. Any suggestions? Thank you very much!
I want to use this switch in an electrolysis cell, to pass pulsed DC from a lab source at various frequencies up to 20MHz (generated by a function generator). To research possible effects I need currents between 8 and 20A at aprox 3-4V.
I find it difficult to measure the cell resistance since it looks like it is not constant throughout the process.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! The device you are looking for is called a MOSFET.

Comment: Do you want to switch 30 amp on and off at a 20 MHz rate? You should describe your application or, as a minimum, tell us the characteristics of the source, drive signal, and load. What you are proposing is not going to be easy to impement.

Comment: Thank you! I am working on a research application on electrochemistry. Basically I have an electrolysis cell (anode, catode and electrolite) through which I am passing DC current. Now I am also trying to pass pulsed DC at various frequencies and duty cycles with the help of my function generator (max 20MHz). I have a DC lab source with 16V and 60Amp. I realise that it is not easy..  unfortunately I am also a beginner in electronics :( but with a fair engineering mind

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need to switch that amount of power at that high of a frequency, you likely need to use GaN or SiC transistors. Be aware that this represents and extremely challenging engineering task, and that you could likely [publish a paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1711/1711.02832.pdf) on just the switching circuit alone.

If you can afford to switch at a lower frequency (say, 10-100kHz range) a half bridge MOSFET circuit is likely more than sufficient for your application, especially one which has a [separately driven internal charge pump](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8106-q1.pdf) to allow for 100% duty cycle PWM.

Comment: thank you very much for the info, this is quite clear!